# Fetch jar files from AWS s3 bucket and display in Jenkins choice parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins and I am trying to fetch all the jar files from S3 bucket and display in choice parameter in Jenkins UI. So we have option to select particular jar file and deploy.

I am using below command for testing purpose in run script and it works.

```
aws s3 ls company-bucketname/test/
```

I have installed "Extensible choice plugin to achive this" and running below groovy script with no luck.

```
def command = 'aws s3 ls company-bucketname/test/ --output text'
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              

def output = proc.in.text
def exitcode= proc.exitValue()
def error = proc.err.text

if (error) {
    println "Std Err: ${error}"
    println "Process exit code: ${exitcode}"
    return exitcode
}

//println output.split()
return output.tokenize()
```

Please let me know if there is better approach to display S3 values in Jenkins choice parameter.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this blog post](https://medium.com/@rijoalvi/jenkins-dynamic-parameters-using-extended-choice-parameter-plugin-and-groovy-1a6ffc41063f), you can use the "Extended Choice Parameter Plugin" and create a script which returns an array of strings that will be used as your choices for the parameter.

It seems like you have the part of fetching the names of the jar files working, so all you need is that plugin and a method returning a list of the choices.